# Locate method references in java simultaneously

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any way to find all references to all the methods present in a single class and do that in a single go.

Suppose I have 3 methods in class A `void m1()`,`void m2()`,`void m3()`, I can't do it via highlighting a method and then pressing `ctrl+shift+G`, on a single method.

But is there a way to check references for all 3 methods at once?

Comment: You should add the eclipse tag. And, for your question, not that I know off.

Comment: thanks, sorry i forgot:)

Comment: Only way I see is (if `A` has only 3 methods which needs to be combined) use `Ctrl+Shift+G` on class `A` and browsed through the search result ;-)

Comment: I would only add `eclipse` if you are using that instead of say IntelliJ or Netbeans.

Comment: Not exactly what you want but you can rename all methods you want to know about and you'll get error markers in every place they are referenced.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of getting call hierarchy for all the methods in a class. But this can be done by using CallHierarchy Api of eclipse.

Here is one example [to get all callers to a method](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/find-all-callers-of-a-method/) you can modify it to get the call hierarchy for all the methods

you can call `public HashSet<IMethod> getCallersOf(IMethod m)` this method for all your methods and save the returned `HashSet<IMethod>` per method.